# увеличение или видоизменение анимированного персанажа

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Я сталкнулся со следующей проблемой: мне нужно увеличивать(не скейлить)/видоизменять  персонажа, т.е. делать его больше или меньше в зависимости от того с чем он сталкнулся. при этом мой персанаж анимирован он бегает, прыгает и т.д. Что бы лучше понять что я хочу сделать, можно посмотреть игру Fat Pusher для android (где игрок набирает вес когда ест и сбрасывает его когда талкает груз)

Буду рад любым предложениям и вариантам решения проблемы

Comment: Так а что значит увеличить в ТВОЕМ случае? Тоже сделать жирным? В случае пушера я вижу скейл + замену модели персонажа на более жирного или худого

Comment: отойдём от МОЕГО случая! как это сделали они? я думаю ответа на этот вопрос будет достаточно что бы я реализовал то что надо мне. мне кажется что они использовали анимацию набора веса (худой человек превращается в толстого), а затем просто изменяли его в blend tree или как то ещё, что по суте своей тоже является скейлом, но я не знаю как это связать с анимациями которые уже есть, замены объектов, как мне кажется там нет, а даже если есть то я так делать не буду